# querying extended File Properties using WMI

Tags: windows, file, namespaces, wmi, extended-properties

Is there a WMI namespace and a class that can be used to obtain the extended properties of a file, such as Owner, Author, Title, Subject, Category, Comments?

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, WMI doesn't provides access to the extended file properties. To obtain them, you can use the [`Folder.GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870.aspx) method (in scripting languages such as PowerShell or VBScript) or the [`IShellDetails.GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775104.aspx) method (in compiled languages such as C++). Take a look at [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674134/detecting-the-version-and-company-name-of-an-exe-using-jscript/2067780#2067780) for an example.

<sup>* Not sure I used the correct terminology here when distinguishing between the languages, so please bear with me and feel free to correct.</sup>

Comment: I was assuming that if I can find a WMI namespace, perhaps, it can work consistently on XP/Vista/Window7. Would you happen to know, if the values for COMPANY_NAME, FILE_VERSION, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_VERSION etc be same on XP/Vista/Window7?

Comment: Most extended properties have different index numbers, except for some basic properties like `Name`, `Size`, `Date modified` etc. Take a look at http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880&page=1 -- this page seems to provide the most complete reference of extended properties available in different Windows versions.

Comment: @Helen: that table is fantastic.

Comment: the table (`[kixtart.org/forums/](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880&page=1)`) isn't available any more

Comment: @Wolf: It's hidden behind a login, but you could use an account from http://bugmenot.com/view/kixtart.org.