# Read music file length in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I was just wondering if there was a way to get the length of an mp3 file in seconds through VBScript into a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Adapted from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563973/113116) to a similar question about JScript.)

You can use the [`GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870.aspx) method of the Windows Shell [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787868.aspx) object to get the audio file length. This technique supports all audio file types whose metadata can be read and displayed by Windows Explorer natively.

However, note that the index of the Length attribute is different on different Windows versions: it's 21 on Windows XP/2003 and 27 on Windows Vista+. See [this page](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880) and [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067780/113116) for details. You will need to take this into account in your script.

Example code:

```
Const LENGTH = 27 ' Windows Vista+
' Const LENGTH = 21 ' Windows XP

Dim oShell  : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace("C:\Music")
Dim oFile   : Set oFile   = oFolder.ParseName("Track.mp3")

Dim strLength : strLength = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, LENGTH)

WScript.Echo strLength
```

Example output:

> 00:05:18

Comment: Does this support all file types?

Comment: @Lugia101101: It works with all file types that your Windows supports. MP3 is supported for sure. To check if other audio formats are supported, open the audio file properties and see if the audio metadata (such as length) shows up in Details. For unsupported file types, `GetDetailsOf` will report length as an empty string.

Comment: I have similar requirements. Thanks for this answer. However this does not work if I pass the folder name through a variable in oShell.Namespace(sFolderName). Any Idea, how to handle this?

Comment: @Karpak, what's your Windows version and the values of `LENGTH` and `sFolderName`? Is the file type MP3 or something else? Do you get any errors or just incorrect result?

Comment: @Helen, It is windows 10. Anyway, when I made the string as variant it started working (instead of sFolderName, I changed to vFolderName and vfoldername as variant. Thx for your answer to this OP. up voted.

Comment: @Karpak, glad you got it working. By the way, `As Variant` sounds like you are using VBA or the regular Visual Basic - these languages are different from VBScript so not everything works the same.

Comment: @Helen, You guessed it right, Yes, I am using VBA. Though they are different, VBA, VB and VBScript have some similarity. I spent quite sometime to identify the duration of the music. Your answer really helped me to resolve the issue that I faced with VBA.

Answer (score 6):

Using Windows Media Player Control library is another way. Before using this make sure the path is correct.

```
Function MediaDuration(path)
    With CreateObject("Wmplayer.OCX")
        .settings.mute = True
        .url = path
        Do While Not .playState = 3 'wmppsPlaying
            WScript.Sleep 50
        Loop
        MediaDuration = Round(.currentMedia.duration) 'in seconds
        'MediaDuration = .currentMedia.durationString 'in hh:mm:ss format
        .Close 
    End With
End Function

WScript.Echo MediaDuration("C:\media\song.mp3")
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to check if the file is supported?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & Wscript.ScriptName & "\", Chr(34) & Wscript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) 
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & Left(Wscript.ScriptName, Len(Wscript.ScriptName)-3) & "exe" & "\", Chr(34) & Wscript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) 

Set Fldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))

Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set DeskFldr=objShell.Namespace(16)
FName=fso.buildpath(DeskFldr.self.path, "Folder Property List.txt")


Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FName, 8, vbtrue)



For x = 0 to 50
    t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(vbnull, x) & " (Shell)" & vbtab
Next
ts.write FLDR.self.path &vbcrlf
ts.Write T1 & vbcrlf
T1=""


For Each FldrItem in FldrItems
    For x = 0 to 50
        t1 = t1 & Fldr.GetDetailsOf(FldrItem, x) & vbtab
    Next
    t1=t1 & vbcrlf
    ts.Write T1
    T1=""
Next

'msgbox FName & "has a tab delimited list of all properties"
```

If you drop a folder on the above it will generate a list of all shell properties for files in the folder. I don't have any mp3 files. It will depend on what software you have installed as to what will happen. Wma files leave duration blank. And the properties change dramatically from Windows version to version.

The first loop gets the properties that are available (by passing null for folderitem), the second the properties for each folderitem.