# VBS code to get audio length

Tags: vbscript

I have vbs script using this script i am able to get audio file data (Path, Name, Size (kb), Type, Date Created, Date Last Accessed, Date Laste Modified) from folder where audio files located but i also want Length of audio file but i have no clu how to do that please help me to modify this code.

```vbs
Dim objFSO, startFolder, OlderThanDate
'Flags for files
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
' Flags for browse dialog
Const BIF_returnonlyfsdirs   = &H0001
Const BIF_dontgobelowdomain  = &H0002
Const BIF_statustext         = &H0004
Const BIF_returnfsancestors  = &H0008
Const BIF_editbox            = &H0010
Const BIF_validate           = &H0020
Const BIF_browseforcomputer  = &H1000
Const BIF_browseforprinter   = &H2000
Const BIF_browseincludefiles = &H4000
currentScriptPath = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "") 
reportFile = currentScriptPath & "FilePropertiesReport.csv"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDlg = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Use the BrowseForFolder method.
Set objStartFolder = objDlg.BrowseForFolder (&H0, _
 "Select the folder you want to report on, su folder will also be reported", BIF_editbox + BIF_returnonlyfsdirs)
' Here we use TypeName to detect the result.
If InStr(1, TypeName(objStartFolder), "Folder") > 0 Then
    startFolder = objStartFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objStartFolder.Title).Path
    'Create report file and add CSV Header
    Set objReportFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(reportfile, ForWriting)
    objReportFile.Write("Path, Name, Size (kb), Type, Date Created, Date Last Accessed, Date Laste Modified,Length"  & chr(13) & chr(10))
    'Run the function
    ReportFiles startFolder
    'Close the report
    objReportFile.Close
    'Ask to open the report now or just close
    strMbox = MsgBox("Reporting Complete. " & chr(13) & chr(10) &"The report has been saved to: " & reportFile & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & "Would you like to open the report now?",4,"Open report now?")
    if strMbox = 6 Then
        objShell.Run reportFile
    End if
Else
    MsgBox "An error has occured."
End if
'----------------------------------------------
' Function
'----------------------------------------------
Function ReportFiles(folderName)
   Dim objFolder, objFile, fileCollection, folderCollection, subFolder
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderName)
   Set fileCollection = objFolder.Files
   For Each objFile In fileCollection
        strFilePath = chr(34) & objFile.Path & chr(34)
        strFileName = chr(34) & objFile.Name & chr(34)
        strFileSize = objFile.Size / 1024
        strFileType = chr(34) & objFile.Type & chr(34)
        strFileDateCreated = objFile.DateCreated
        strFileDateLastAccessed = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        strFileDateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
        objReportFile.Write(strFilePath & "," & strFileName & "," & strFileSize & "," & strFileType & "," & strFileDateCreated & "," & strFileDateLastAccessed & "," & strFileDateLastModified & chr(13) & chr(10))
   Next
    'Loop for each sub folder
    Set folderCollection = objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each subFolder In folderCollection
       ReportFiles subFolder.Path
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811602/read-music-file-length-in-vbscript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read music file length in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811602/read-music-file-length-in-vbscript)

Comment: Hi All Thanks for the reply actually i want data Using the Browse For Folder method can anybody help me to modify my code.

Comment: Try [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx) for guidance