# how to get Music Duration using asp on W2K12 server

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, duration

this question is a follow-on from [Read music file length in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811602/read-music-file-length-in-vbscript) but as I am new I don't seem to be able to add comments or ask questions on that post :(.

So, I have copied the code as posted by @Helen as per below and it works perfectly on my Win10 laptop, however when I try the same on my W2K12 R2 server, the results are sadly very different. I still get some properties, such as you might expect from a normal file, but the duration is blank. I have modified it to pull all properties (ie length = 0 to 1000 in a loop) and some properties are populated but nothing looking like duration... :(

```
Const LENGTH = 27 ' Windows Vista+
' Const LENGTH = 21 ' Windows XP

Dim oShell  : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace("C:\Music")
Dim oFile   : Set oFile   = oFolder.ParseName("Track.mp3")

Dim strLength : strLength = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, LENGTH)

WScript.Echo strLength
```

Does anyone understand why this won't work on my W2K12 server?

I have tried changing the folder attributes from "general" to "optimised for music" but still no luck..

Comment: That seems to depends on Windows Media Player installation

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure file permission is correct.
2. And you can try run vbs like this: Run > cmd > `"%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe" C:\test.vbs`