# Get Image Resolution via VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

How can I get an image resolution in DPI with VBScript?

for example

```
Res= GET "M.jpg" Resolution
If Res > 100
   Echo "GOODQ"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gan get the image DPI using the [`HorizontalResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630569.aspx) and [`VerticalResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630578.aspx) properties of the [`WIA.ImageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630506.aspx) scripting object:

```
Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

objImage.LoadFile "C:\M.jpg"

If objImage.HorizontalResolution > 100 Then
  Log.Message "GOODQ (" & objImage.HorizontalResolution & " DPI)"
End If
```

Just for completeness, there's another solution for Windows Vista and later — using the [`Folder.GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787870.aspx) method to read the image DPI from the extended file properties. But the code will be longer and a bit messier, because:

- The index of the *Horizontal resolution* and *Vertical resolution* file properties are different on different Windows versions (see [this page](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880) and [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067780/113116) for details).
- The extended file properties return DPI as a string like *240 dpi*; you may need to convert it to a number.

  ```
  ' For Windows 7
  Const HORIZONTAL_RESOLUTION = 161
  Const VERTICAL_RESOLUTION = 163

  Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\MyFolder")
  Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("M.jpg")

  Dim strDpi : strDpi = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFile, HORIZONTAL_RESOLUTION) ' Returns DPI as a string like "240 dpi"
  Dim dpi : dpi = ToInt(strDpi)

  If dpi > 100 Then
    Log.Message "GOODQ (" & dpi & " DPI)"
  End If

  ' Extracts a number from a string, e.g. "240 dpi" -> 240
  ' NB: no error handling
  Function ToInt(ValueStr)
    Dim objRE : Set objRE = New RegExp
    objRE.Pattern = "\d+"
    Dim colMatches : Set colMatches = objRE.Execute(ValueStr)
    ToInt = CLng(colMatches(0).Value)
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Just Wonderful Helen , THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using [WIA Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630827.aspx) Library.

```
Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
objImage.LoadFile "M.jpg"

If objImage.Width > 100 And objImage.Height > 100 Then
    WScript.Echo "GOODQ" & vbNewLine & "Width: " & _ 
        objImage.Width & vbNewLine & _
        "Height: " & objImage.Height
End If
```

Comment: Thanks QuickNull but your code is getting width and height but not resolution in DPI :(